# How can I get Alexa working on my iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have been checking out the Alexa Skills kit the past few days. I have also been poring through the documentations for both the Skills kit and the Voice Service. I am just having a little hiccup trying to understand the flow. I have implemented one of amazon's sample skills (favourite colour sample) in the developer console and also wrote a sample lambda function to handle the type of response that will be delivered. Its working on the test simulator and what left is basically getting lambda running through my ios app. However I have the impression that I don't have to use the voice service. Am I wrong? I am quite confused, it would be awesome if anybody who has some more clarity could shed some light on the matter. If I get lambda working also, I think it will accept requests that are in a particular format. Where do I have to send the encoded audio to get a json response to send to the skills kit? To the Alexa Voice Service?

Also I am authenticating my app using cognito and dynamo db. If I were to use Alexa Voice Service, then it is mentioned that the user will have to also login to amazon. So do I still have to work with the login with amazon sdk? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer your question directly, but I would encourage you to take a peek at this. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/tags/alexa-skills-kit/. BNR did a series that takes a lot of the guesswork, uploading, etc. out of the equation. If you're coming from Swift, the learning curve for JavaScript isn't that steep.

Comment: Maybe you could pay Alexa enough to be willing to work on your app? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Amazon documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/content/avs-api-overview#authorization) there are two ways to interact with Alexa:

Sounds like you want to implement the app thru the **Companion** method.

As far as the JSON goes, i am currently resolving that issue now, (will post answer once I have it resolved).

Basically you have to use AVFoundation to capture audio from iPhone and send 2 https messages to Alexa *(One message with JSON Body  & the second message with audio captured as body.)* [Bases on Documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/avs-http2-requests)

1. ***Companion App***
   (You have a device (such as a smart speaker) that you want to add Alexa to. So, you build in support for AVS. Great! Now you need a way to authorize it and associate it with the user's account. This is the "companion app" approach. The companion app connects to your smart product and allows the user to login and authorize the speaker to use Alexa and connect to their Amazon account.)

   [Mobile](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-an-android-or-ios-mobile-app)  OR  [Website](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-a-website)
2. ***AVS App***
   (You don't have a device you need to authorize - instead you want to speak to Alexa from within your Android/Iphone application.)

   [Android or Iphone](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-mobile-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can find a swift example on github on how to implement a iOS AVS client

https://github.com/chintan1891/iOS-Alexa

Comment: Is there any android sample?