# How to integrate Alexa feature in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, alexa-voice-service, alexa-skills-kit

Am trying to implement Alexa feature in an iOS app. From the amazon developer documents, I find that it requires the `access token`, to send the HTTP POST requests. And I did the `Login using Amazone`. Now I have the `access token`. I don't know how to continue to the next level. Anyone can help me to get implement `Alexa` feature in an iOS app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Alexa working on my iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915178/how-can-i-get-alexa-working-on-my-ios-app)

Comment: @Erumaru By the help of that answer only I did the login with amazon feature. But I didn't get any solution from that answer to implement Alexa in iOS app. It is posted 3 years back.